# Increment integer in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this piece of code in python 3:

```
i=0
for item in splitDict(Team, 3):
    i+=1
    print("{1} #{0}".format(i,item))
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
i=0
for item in splitDict(Team, 3):
    print("{1} #{0}".format(i+=1,item))
```

Notice I've put the increment into the format statement.
But when I run it I get the error:

```
print("{1} #{0}".format(i+=1,item))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is how can I get it to increment in the print statement?

Comment: Why? Obscuring your code to save a line; you would have trouble finding a popular language where that is less idiomatic than python.

Comment: This seems like an xy problem

Comment: Just use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and you don't have to increment manually.

Comment: Assignment in Python is not an expression but a statement in itself. You can't use it where you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly you are really wanting to use `enumerate` to solve your problem.  But to answer the specific question of "how can I increment `i` within the `print` statement" ... then you can do the following **very ugly thing** (its not strictly *within*):

```
i=0
for item in splitDict(Team, 3):
    i += print("{1} #{0}".format(i + 1, item)) or 1
```

But you shouldn't.  Use `enumerate`:

```
for i, item in enumerate(splitDict(Team, 3)):
    print("{1} #{0}".format(i, item))
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm at the beginning of my journey with python. Lessons liked this help mer understand what I should and shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I couldn't get your original code working, this is the best I could come up with

```
splitDict = ['a','b','c','d','e']
x=0
for i,item in enumerate(splitDict, start=x):
    print ('#'+str(i),item)
```